# Can't make jquery UI work in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I've been trying all day but can't make this work. Here is my setup:

I have installed: jQuery 2.1.3 and jQuery.UI.Combined 1.11.2.

In BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

However in ~/Content/themes/base/ their names are missing "jquery.ui." prefix.

In my layout i have:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

I can confirm that jquery and jquery UI are loaded on the page by looking in firebug but when I try to call the function `dialog()` I'm getting and error saying it's not a function.

```
<td>
                    <div style="width:100px;height:30px; background:#009814" onclick="showPopup(this)"> </div>
                    <div style="position:relative" class="input-group"> Indicatoris go here </div>
</td>

    function showPopup(elem)
            {
                var el = $(elem);
                //el.siblings()[0] it has only 1 sibling (a div)
                el.siblings()[0].dialog({
                    autoOpen: false
                });
                el.siblings()[0].dialog('open');
            }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: themes have nothing to do with javascript errors

Comment: javascript files are loaded successfully?

Comment: Include your code that is generating the error.

Comment: @Soproni I believe so. i can see the jqueryUI file in firebug but it doesn't contain a 'function dialog()'

Comment: var dialog = $.widget( "ui.dialog", { you should find that code in the jquery ui javascript file, i check the jquery ui1.11.2 javascript file just now and find the function for dialog

Comment: The function doesn't tell me anything, because a) I have no idea what elem is, and b) it doesn't tell me how you call it.  However, you have to attach the dialog to an element in order for you to call it, and you're not showing the code in which you are initializing your jquery ui dialog.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch it's an onclick function on a div: `showPopup(this)`

Comment: are you actually using onclick=?  or are you using jquery .click()?  Just show all the relevant code... stop hiding stuff from us.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch hope this is all you need

Comment: You're getting the error because the square-brackets notation `[0]` fetches the HTMLElement, not the jQuery object. Use `.eq(0)` instead, or wrap it in *another* `$(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code.  First, I'd suggest not using onclick handler and instead use a jquery click event, but I won't harp on that.

I will assume your script is in a proper script block, if not it should be.

Next, your problem is that your `el.siblings()[0]` code doesn't return a jQuery object, but rather an HTML Dom DIV object, and since jQueryUI works on jQuery objects that's why it can't find dialog.  This is an easy fix.

```
function showPopup(elem)
        {
            var el = $(elem);
            //el.siblings()[0] it has only 1 sibling (a div)
            var sib = $(el.siblings()[0]).dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });
            sib.dialog('open');
        }
```

So, your problem has nothing to do with MVC, or with bundling, or any of the other issues you thought it was... it was simply bad jQuery code.

Comment: just to clarify, that would be `el.siblings().eq(0)` or `el.siblings().first()`, both of which would also return the first sibling as a jQuery object without the need to wrap it in a `$()`.